# How to Create Server from my Local Machine with Internet Connection?

Tags: 14.04, server

I want to know How to setup Server with ubuntu from my local machine? whether it cost me extra ? want some brief explanation regarding this...

Answer (score 0):

"Server" installations are normally installations geared towards primarily just packages for lighter-weight UI's and less "Workstation/Client" packages. In the end you can really take any installation and add/remove the packages you want to create your machine.

The underlying rule to move towards performance is less=more. Meaning only install the packages/binaries you require to get your "server" online for whatever "service" you plan on hosting.

When it comes to cost or licensing you are looking at what your support contract will be for Ubuntu and the cost of power for your machine.